# How can I use bootstrap v4 in latest Angular?

Tags: angular, npm

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

makes new version of bootstrap.. but I am better at using v4 than this.

how can I install specific version but not latest one in angular?

Comment: npm install bootstrap@<version>, to install particular version

Comment: Thanks, it works :0 Does it work after I already set up latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
npm install bootstrap@4 --save
```

Comment: Thanks!! now I can use it :)

Answer (score 1):

Install bootstrap via npm

```
npm Install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta  --save
```

Set it in angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
         "styles.css",
         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/
          bootstrap.min.css"
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta --save
```

basically

```
npm install bootstrap@<versionno> --save
```

[bootstrap-v4-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-v4-dev)

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-write the dependency as bootstrap with version in your packaage.json file. Like below::

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    **"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",**
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  } 
or you do this in way.
npm install bootstrap@4 --save-dev